# How to loop RestClient request passing id and then appending to response

Tags: c#, json, rest, rest-client

The API I am using to grab data from is very limited.  The only way I can get data out is via a GET request passing the identifier of the record I require.  Issue is I could have multiple ID's I need data for.  Is there an efficient way of looping a request and appending the json response to a List and adding that id to that JSON?

```
 private static List<Question> getQuestions(string bearer, List<int> customerids)
 {
   //the example below passes the customer ID 1.  What I want to do is pass customerids

   var qq = new RestClient("https://server.test.net/api/customers/1/");
   qq.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", bearer);
   var request = new RestRequest("questions");
   var response = qq.Execute(request);
   string rawResponse = response.Content;
   List<Question> questions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Question>>(rawResponse);
              
   return questions;
}
```

I need to run the API call through a loop (therefore a call for customer 1, 6, 776 if they exist in the customerids list) instead of currently its set to customer 1.  I then want to append the result to the rawResponse together with the customer id as it doesnt exist in the data i pull back.

Unfortunately it's probably not the best way to run this and have had many conversations with the software supplier about reaching response limits but its the only way I can extract data by running in a loop and then joining the customerid back as it doesnt exist within the data i pull back, even though I can use it within the get request.

Therefore results would look like (where customer id didnt exist within the response, however added by passing from customerids list after the call, and appending all id's to same response dataset:

| customerid | question id | answer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 43 | true |
| 6 | 76 | Married |
| 774 | 76 | Single |

Question Class:

```
public class Question
{
public int QuestionID {get; set;}
public string answer {get; set;}
}
```

Potential foreach need some help in appending results for each customer also adding the associated customer id to the result

```
foreach (var item in customerids)
{
var qq = new RestClient("https://system.test.net/api/customers/" + item + "/");
qq.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", bearer);
var request = new RestRequest("questions");
var response = qq.Execute(request);
string rawResponse = response.Content;
}
```

Comment: can you share the code of `Question` class? can there be more than one questions for one customer?

Comment: Did you try using foreach loop and passing individual customerid to the URL instead of `1` ?

Comment: Hi thanks for your comments.  I have added the Question class, although I do have a lot more fields, but for simplicity in displaying the issue just provided the main ones.   Yes they could be many questions for a customer.

Comment: I did also try the foreach above, but how would I append to the response for each customer?  Moreover, how would I add the customer id to the rawresponse as another element/field?

Comment: The API response does not have customerid in it? You need to create a list of Question outside the loop. If the `rawResponse` is json of collection of Question then you should deserialize the json to List<Question> and then add it to the other list using AddRange method.

Comment: Thanks for your help I will try that. Just a question though will the line string rawResponse = response.Content; append all questions, the issue I have is how would I know which customer the question is for, hence why I wanted to do it within the loop.

Comment: Can you share a sample json you are getting from the API for one customerid?

Comment: It’s just the questionid and answer as above table, string is {questionid:76; answer:”Married”} for example. There is no customer Id at all but I’m passing that in the get request that I need back so I know what question is associated with which customer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have almost solved the issue based on the comments above.

I think the only part which is not solved yet is how to assign customerid to the questions returned from the API.

Once you receive the JSON from the API, you should deserialize it to a list of Questions and then assign CustomerId to each of the questions in the list.

You can either use SELECT LINQ method or loop thru the list of Questions.

In the following code, I have used approach of using SELECT LINQ method.

```
public class Question
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}

private static List<Question> GetQuestions(string bearer, List<int> customerids)
    {
        var list = new List<Question>();

        // Create RestClient with base address.
        var restClient = new RestClient("https://server.test.net/api");

        // Add authorization header.
        restClient.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", bearer);

        // Loop thru customerids
        foreach (var customerid in customerids)
        {
            // Create RestRequest with URL for each customerid.
            var request = new RestRequest($"api/customers/{customerid}/questions", Method.GET);

            var res = restClient.Execute(request);
            var content = res.Content;

            // Deserialize response to a list of Questions.
            // here I am assuming that the JSON returned from the API is for a list of Questions.
            var questions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Question>>(content);

            // Creating new list of Questions with customerid assigned to them.
            // Here I am assuming that the JSON from the API does not have customerId value in it. 
            questions = questions.Select(q => new Question { Answer = q.Answer, QuestionId = q.QuestionId, CustomerId = customerid }).ToList();

            // Add questions to the list to be returned.
            list.AddRange(questions);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

I hope this will help you solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, you have helped me a great deal and I have learned usage of LINQ within an API call on data that requires change.  I'm new to C# so really appreciate all the help.  Upvoted :)